# PWA Lighthouse and Webpack Bundles

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I've written a PWA with create-react-app using React 17 and the cra-template-pwa. My app is pretty basic but does load a handful of modules such as Axios and a UI component library.

Some background to the question: I'm trying to be clever and get good Lighthouse performance numbers on my PWA by using dynamic module loading. Basically I want Lighthouse to measure the load of my app skeleton while everything else gets loaded after (I understand this isn't going to help my users much but I have a reason for wanting to optimize for high lighthouse numbers).

So my approach is: in my index.js, I statically import only react and react-dom, then use React.lazy and suspense to import my App component. I had initially triggered the import in a useEffect hook, but in my infinite cleverness decided to trigger the import in the page load event. It is working fine.

Then in my App.js, since not everything is a React component, I'm using:
const chunk = import('./appChunk.js').then(...) to load the rest of my various modules.

Again this is all working fine.

But the behavior I'm seeing is: In Chrome dev tools, Application tab under Service Workers, it shows my service worker as "Trying to Install" for an extended period of time. When I look at the Network tab I see my app is loading a boatload of modules.  It seems my production CRA build has ~255 modules in it totaling 10MB. As soon as these are all done loading, the service worker status goes green and says Installed, and my PWA prompt is triggered.

However, Lighthouse times out before this finishes, and fails to create any output.  With my service worker unregistered, I'm getting really good Lighthouse performance numbers. But turning on the service worker results in a lighthouse error and no report.

This leaves me with a lot of questions, and I'm not sure the order to ask them lol. I'm not sure why my app build is generating 255 bundles. I'm not sure why Chrome is waiting for all these bundles to load before marking my service worker as installed, or how Chrome even knows or cares about them. While the modules are loading I have a loading spinner running. Since all the imports were triggered async, shouldn't Chrome/Lighthouse already see my app as loaded?

I created a PWA a year ago, similar in scope and size. In that case I ejected the React app in order to manually configure the bundling. I didn't have these problems. To be honest I don't remember what I did in configuring though- I followed some blog somewhere and have lost the link to that. But with dynamic module load supported in CRA now I thought I could get by without ejecting.

Any insight into what is going on and/or how I might get to the bottom of it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Another strange detail. If I don't register the service worker, it doesn't load all those packages. It loads just a handful and is availably quickly. But just by switching unregister to register, it then loads all of them before becoming active as a PWA. I really don't know what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is going on. The CRA PWA settings are design to precache all the static assets, and my UI library has several hundred SVG icons. I'm currently looking at ways disable Google Workbox precaching without ejecting.